# Treating 1D array (pointer) as 3D matrix at run time in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I receive some image data as `unsigned char *image = load_image(…);`

This data is a 3D matrix: `x` (char),`y` (char) and `channel (RGB)` (char).

How can I access each element as `image[x][y][channel]` by overloading `[]`? E.g. row 999, column 10000, green channel: `image[999][10000][1]`

Clarifications:

1. I'd like to use C multi-dimensional array syntax: `array[x][y][z]`, not `array[x * height * channels + y * channels + z]`
2. I can access a 1D array as a 2D array:

   ```
   unsigned char (*imageMatrix)[height] = (unsigned char (*)[height])image
   imageMatrix[x][y] = 100
   ```
3. [I already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47267624/) how to do it in pure C. Here I want to know how it can be better achieved in C++.

Comment: You can create a `vector<vector<vector<char>>> image`, and assign it accordingly with your data. You'll have to decide which order of the data is better for you (and of course size will be an issue).

Comment: I need to assign `image = load_image(…)` and `load_image(…)` is type `(char *)`

Comment: You can't overload `char *`.

Comment: Don’t overload `[]` to pretend you have a nested array, that’s a bad (= easy to use wrong, misleading) API. Instead, overload `()` to work with your multi-dimensional index arguments (`image(x, y, channel)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can create `Image` class with a function that will get what you want

```
class Image {
    int imgSize;
    char * img;

public:
    Image(): imgSize(0), img(nullptr) {}
    Image(char* image, int size): imgSize(size), img(image) {}

    char getPixel(int x, int y, int z) {
        if(x < imgSize && y < imgSize && z < imgSize) {
            return img[x * imgSize * imgSize + y * imgSize + z];
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }

    char operator(int x, int y, int z) {
        // The same as getPixel
    }
}
```

`getPixel` is in my opinion the best approach because whenever you call it, you (and people working with your code) will exactly know what you do thanks to its name (even after 6 months you will immediately know you get a pixel). Overloading `operator()` is also a good approach, but I wouldn't use it were it to cause confusion or unwanted behavior. Both hide the internal structure of your class and don't require any proxy classes.

Overloading `operator[]` is an option, but to support chaining like `[][][]` you need proxy classes which will badly affect the performance of your code if not designed correctly.

You can read [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) to learn more.

Comment: “what does it mean to call an image?” is a red herring. Multidimensional matrix-indexing via `()` is extremely common and well understood. And treating an image as a matrix, well, that’s also common (although I’d prefer if this didn’t work directly but rather via a `buffer()` getter or similar).

Comment: I also disagree with your advice that “overloading `operator[]` might be good as well”. I’ll refer to the [relevant C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) and its successors.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access each element as `image[x][y][channel]` by overloading `[]`?

When you overload an array operator for the image class, it can only support the syntax `image[x]` in its interface.

In order to be able to support `image[x][y]`, `image[x]` needs to return an object or a reference to an object that needs to support the array operator.

In order to be able to support `image[x][y][z]`, `image[x][y]` needs to return an object or a reference to an object that needs to support the array operator.

Here's a sample program that demonstrates how it can be done.

**Disclaimer** Please note that this is not production ready code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Image
{
   Image(unsigned int x,
         unsigned int y,
         unsigned int z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z), data(new unsigned char [x*y*z]) {}

   // Need appropriate copy constructor and destructor.

   // Helper classes to support the 3D array operator syntax.

   struct image_2
   {
      image_2(Image& im, unsigned i, unsigned j) : im_(im), i_(i), j_(j) {}
      unsigned char& operator[](unsigned k)
      {
         assert( k < im_.z_ );
         unsigned int index = i_*im_.y_*im_.z_ + j_*im_.z_ + k;
         return im_.data[index];
      }

      Image& im_;
      unsigned int i_;
      unsigned int j_;
   };

   struct image_1
   {
      image_1(Image& im, unsigned i) : im_(im), i_(i) {}

      image_2 operator[](unsigned int j)
      {
         assert( j < im_.y_ );
         return image_2(im_, i_, j);
      }

      Image& im_;
      unsigned int i_;
   };

   // The toplevel array operator
   image_1 operator[](unsigned i)
   {
      assert( i < x_ );
      return image_1(*this, i);
   }

   unsigned x_;
   unsigned y_;
   unsigned z_;
   unsigned char* data;
};

int main()
{
   unsigned int x = 5;
   unsigned int y = 5;
   unsigned int z = 3;
   Image im(5, 5, 3);

   for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < x; ++i )
   {
      for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < y; ++j )
      {
         for ( unsigned int k = 0; k < z; ++k )
         {
            // Set some arbitrary value
            im[i][j][k] = (i+1) + (j+1)*5 + (k+1)*5;

            // Get the value
            std::cout << (int)im[i][j][k] << " ";
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
11 16 21
16 21 26
21 26 31
26 31 36
31 36 41
12 17 22
17 22 27
22 27 32
27 32 37
32 37 42
13 18 23
18 23 28
23 28 33
28 33 38
33 38 43
14 19 24
19 24 29
24 29 34
29 34 39
34 39 44
15 20 25
20 25 30
25 30 35
30 35 40
35 40 45
```